Orthogonality and modularity in model theory
I am trying to understand some definitions in model theory. But they are to abstract to me. So I need some examples to show me what on earth they are talking about.
So I am working in the theory of separably closed fields $\mathbf{SCF}_{p,\nu}$ of characteristic $p>0$ of finite degree of imperfection $\nu:=[K:K^p]<+\infty$. I stuck at the following two definitions:
Orthonality
Let $X,Y$ be $A$-definable sets. We say $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal if for any $B\supset A$, $a\in X$ and $b\in Y$, we have $a$ is independent from $b$ over $B$.
I think this could be related to algebraic independency. But I can not come up with an example.
Modularity
Let $G$ be a group defined over $A$. We say $G$ is modular if for any finite tuple $\overline a=(a_1,\dots, a_r)$ of elements in $X$ and $B\supset A$, $\overline a$ is independent from $acl(B)$ over $acl(A\cap \overline a)\cap acl(B)$.
For me, the word modular group stands for $PGL(2,\mathbb Z)$. It seems that here it means something else? Or is there any relationship?

(1) Please tell us what reference you are using to learn about the theory of separably closed fields. It's easier to write a helpful answer if you know what someone knows already! (2) "Independent" here means independent in the sense of non-forking in a general stable theory. But this has a more algebraic interpretation in the special case of $\mathsf{SCF}_{p,\nu}$. (3) Modularity has nothing to do with $PGL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. The definition is just what you wrote down. Of course, you need to understand what "independent" means (see point (2)) and what $\mathrm{acl}$ means in this theory.
